# Matching data to hashtable (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am having an issue

I have created 2 hash tables - $Offices and $Departments and imported from .csv
The $Departments has headers OfficialDepartment and DepartmentGlCode
I want to search this hashtable for the key 'ICT Dept' and return the value.
This works stand alone
[image: Working Hash Table search]

However, if I add it to my script, I get a problem with my GetEnumerator (Missing "=")
I will post the code as far as the breakpoint. You may ask what the Get-ADUser part is there for, well once I have this part working, I will be looking for $_.Department from AD to match against the hash table

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
$Offices = @{}
$Offices = Import-Csv -Path "D:\temp\OfficeGlCodes.csv" -Delimiter ","
$Departments = @{}
$Departments = Import-Csv -Path "D:\temp\DepartmentGlCodes.csv" -Delimiter ","
$Results = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true -and Description -eq "Staff" -and Office -eq "Head Office"} -Properties POBox, Office, Department | ForEach-Object {
    $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Department      =   $_.Department
        Office          =   $_.Office
        OriginalGLCode  =   $_.POBox
        Date            =   $StartTime.ToString("d")
        $Departments.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {
            if ($_.OfficialDepartment -eq 'ICT Dept') {
                Write-Output $_.DepartmentGlCode
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
ParserError: \\opvx341\homeshares$\Mike.Davidson\24. GL Code Project\initial.ps1:15:37
```

Line |
15 |          $Departments.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {
|                                      ~
| Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.

Comment: You create empty hashtables and then you immediately overwrite them with the output from `Import-Csv` - so now you no longer have hash tables. What are the column names/headers in the CSV files, and which column do you want to use as a lookup key?

Comment: When you say that I no longer have hashtables? I thought I needed to create them empty first. From my screenshot, it shows that I do have hashtables? I have 2 columns, OfficialDepartment and DepartmentGlCode - the lookup should be OfficialDepartment and in this case ICT Dept is what I am looking for - This should return corresponding value of TEST66

Comment: And what about the offices? What Column names does that CSV have?

Comment: You don't "need to create them empty first" - this line *does* assign a hashtable ```$Offices = @{}``` but as @mathaisr.jessen says you overwrite it in the next line using ```$Offices = Import-Csv ...```, where ```Import-Csv``` returns either a single ```PSCustomObject``` or a ```System.Object[]``` array depending on how many results are returned.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.3#using-the-assignment-operator - "When you assign a value to a variable in PowerShell, the variable is created if it didn't already exist."

Comment: OK so I can get rid of creating the empty hashtags, but please see screenshot where, standalone, it does work. The $Offices contains OfficialOffice and OfficeGlCode - I haven't really got to that bit yet but once I have this first issue fixed

Comment: I will be basically doing this: Check if AD Department is in hash table, if it is, write DepartmentGLCode to a variable ($GLCode), if OfficialDepartment not found, log it. If found but DepartmentGLCode doesn't match $_.POBox, log it. Then, if AD department is found in OfficialDepartment but is blank, then look up $_.Office against $Offices and write it's corresponding OfficeGlCode to $GLCode. The end result is, if AD $_.POBox is incorrect it will get logged and the log will contain what the GLCode should be - some departments dont have a GLCode and therefore fall back to the Office GLCode.

Answer (score 4):

You are currently creating empty hash tables, and then you immediately overwrite them with the output from `Import-Csv` - so now you no longer have hash tables.

Do this instead:

```
$StartTime = Get-Date

# create empty hashtable
$Offices = @{}
# populate hashtable with data from CSV
Import-Csv -Path "D:\temp\OfficeGlCodes.csv" -Delimiter "," |ForEach-Object {
  $Offices[$_.OfficialOffice] = $_
}

# create empty hashtable
$Departments = @{}
# populate hashtable with data from CSV
Import-Csv -Path "D:\temp\DepartmentGlCodes.csv" -Delimiter "," |ForEach-Object {
  $Departments[$_.OfficialDepartment] = $_
}

$Results = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true -and Description -eq "Staff" -and Office -eq "Head Office"} -Properties POBox, Office, Department | ForEach-Object {
    # create an ordered hashtable to temporarily hold the output object's properties
    $properties = [ordered]@{
        Department       =   $_.Department
        Office           =   $_.Office
        OriginalGLCode   =   $_.POBox
        Date             =   $StartTime.ToString("d")
    }
    # now use hash tables to look up department/office codes and conditionally add property values
    $properties['DepartmentGlCode'] = if ($Departments.Contains($_.Department)){
        $Departments[$_.Department].DepartmentGlCode
    } 
    else {
        $Offices[$_.Office].OfficeGlCode
        # log discrenpancy here
    }

    # create and output final object
    [PSCustomObject]$properties
}
```

Comment: This is really good and I apprieciate it - i've been working on this for the last week! So the final part. I have output $Results to CSV, however, I now need to do the following: If originalGLCode doesnt match DepartmentGLCode, update populate new variable $NewGlCode to DepartmentGLCode. BUT if DepartmentGLCode is blank, update $NewGlCode to OfficeGLCode - also, only output to log file for when GLCode was incorrect and there $NewGlCode is populated. Once log files work 100% I will be looking into updating $_.POBox for each user with $NewGlCode

Comment: @Bash I've updated the code to show how you can construct the result object in multiple steps, this should allow you to implement your logging and additional logic :)

Comment: OK I was ok up till there, i'm lost now, I will keep plugging away at it - thanks Mathias

Comment: What i'm trying to write now, is: if $_.POBox -ne $Departments[$_.Department].DepartmentGlCode then write $Departments[$_.Department].DepartmentGlCode to variable $NewGLCode, but if $Departments[$_.Department].DepartmentGlCode is blank, write $Offices[$_.Office].OfficeGlCode to $NewGLCode

Comment: $date=((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')) 
$Results | Export-Csv d:\temp\GLCodeUpdateLogs-$date.csv -NoTypeInformation -append but only if $NewGLCode is populated

Comment: @Bash Feel free to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :)

Comment: Thanks Mathias - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76474772/creating-a-new-variable-based-upon-other-variables-not-matching