# Creating a new variable based upon other variables not matching

Tags: powershell

OK - big thanks Mathias for [previous help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76473060/45375).

I have $variableA, $variableB, $VariableC and $VariableResult

What I want to do is:

```
if $variableA -eq $variableB set $Status to TRUE
if $variableA -ne $variableB set $Status to FALSE and set $VariableResult to content of $VariableB
if $variableA -ne $variableB but $variableB is empty, set $Status to FALSE and set $VariableResult to content of $VariableC
```

This should mean that `$VariableResult` will only contain something if `$VariableA` is incorrect and $Status will only be set if `$VariableA` is incorrect.

Comment: What specific issue are you having translating this pseudocode to actual code?

Comment: "if $variableA -eq $variableB set $Status to TRUE" can be expressed very simply: `$Status = $variableA -eq $variableB`

Answer (score 0):

> if $variableA -eq $variableB set $Status to TRUE
> if $variableA -ne $variableB set $Status to FALSE and set $VariableResult to content of $VariableB
> if $variableA -ne $variableB but $variableB is empty, set $Status to FALSE and set $VariableResult to content of $VariableC

```
$Status = $variableA -eq $variableB

$variableResult = if (!$Status) {
    if ($variableB) {
        $variableB
    }
    else {
        $variableC
    }
}
else {
    $variableA
}
```

Comment: A different issue now. Things are working, but as the script iterates through AD users, it should write out to .csv - the problem is that the variableresult doesn't write to .csv until the next pass - therefore my .csv line is correct except for variableresult which is from the previous user. I thought I could fix this by moving the "}" to after the export-csv but this produces a Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal error

Comment: Status           =   $Properties.CurrentGLCode -eq $Properties.DepartmentGLCode
                            variableResult = if (!$Status) {
                              if ($Properties.DepartmentGLCode) {
                                $Properties.DepartmentGLCode
                              }
                              else {
                                $Properties.OfficeGLCode
                              }
                            }
                            else {
                              $Properties.CurrentGLCode
                            }

Comment: }
    # create and output final object
    $date=((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')) 
    #[PSCustomObject]$properties |  Where-Object {$properties.Status -eq $false} |Export-Csv d:\temp\GLCodeUpdateLogs-$date.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
    [PSCustomObject]$properties | Export-Csv d:\temp\GLCodeUpdateLogs-$date.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
  
}